# cannot move android widget to top or bottom of screen

Tags: android, android-widget

i have a custom widget which i have shrinked 100dp x 100dp  but i have an issue that the widget only can be set in the middle of the screen , it cannot be put on the bottom or on the top of the screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="75dp"
android:minHeight="75dp"
android:updatePeriodMillis="18000000"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
 android:resizeMode="none">

</appwidget-provider>


 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/linerlay"         
     android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/wid_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/d"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"

                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                android:textColor="#640909"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                 />
             <TextView
         android:id="@+id/sv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16sp"

                 />

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/t"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         />
 </LinearLayout>
```